# Sending phone call without TAPI installed?

Tags: connection, phone-call

I am developing an auto-dialer application to send out mass phone calls to a list of clients from a database. I am using Dialogic's Diva SDK 5.5 WIN API to develop this application. I believe my code is running correctly and I can have the application begin the process of sending a call out, however the issue is that it stops working and just returns "Dialing" as the progress status. The call fails to do anything other than this and I have now been troubleshooting it for quite a while and found return code from one of the error tests that reports there is no TAPI installed on my computer.

Is TAPI required to be able to send phone calls successfully from any computer or is it likely the issue is just an error in my code? I am using the Dialogic Diva UM-Analog-4 media board and I believe I have all of the cables hooked up correctly to it. I cannot find anything that helps answer this question in the Dialogic manuals, any help or insight into this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which of the many APIs are you using? What version of Windows? You mentioned the 5.5 SDK, but is it the Diva API, Diva Component API, Diva API for .NET, etc.? What is your development environment? Do you call "DivaInitialize" as your first command or something else like LineInitializeEX? As of Dec 2015, Dialogic stopped supporting TAPI on their Diva boards (though it still works), so calls to one of their direct APIs should not require TAPI. However using these older 5.5 drivers, especially if you are using the COM controls, it may sit on top of TAPI. You may want to check the follwing:

1. run services.msc from a command prompt and make sure the "Telephony" service is running. It should be set to "automatic" if you are going to use TAPI
2. Check that the TSP is installed for your Dialogic card. You should have seen something related to TAPI during the install. The file "divasp.tsp" should be in your system32 folder
3. Make sure you ran and saved the settings in the Dialogic Configuration Manager for lines, boards, and especially "services" so it connects the correct API for you to use.

Comment: I am using the Diva API for .NET, on version 1709, and using Visual Studio 2017 for developing. 
Yes, I call “DivaInitialize” as the first command. The device name I’m using for the program is Dialogic Diva UM-Analog-4 PCIe.

Comment: The Telephony service is installed and running, however it is set to manual and I am unsure of how to set it to automatic. The “divasp.tsp” is installed in the system32 folder as well. 
The program seems to run perfectly fine connecting to the proper API’s but the call just simply doesn’t go through and the program can’t get past the “dialing…” status return. Is this possibly because the Telephony service is set to manual instead of automatic or is that unrelated?

Comment: Yes, It should be set to "automatic", but if it was started  manually, it should still work until you restart the computer. To change startup type of a service, double click the service to open its Properties window. The General tab opens by default. You can then find the ‘Startup Type‘ and change it to Manual, Automatic (Delayed Start), Automatic, or Disabled. Make it automatic.

Comment: The Startup Type on the Telephony Properties is not changeable for me. I can see the dropdown box where it is selected but the box won't let me click on it to change it. Thank you for your help on this continued nuisance

Comment: Try one of the sample programs I mentioned or one of the Diva samples and see if they work. That will eliminate the board as an issue and possibly let you know if it is your code or not.